# Count the amount of values by Date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below and my goal is to create a trend line chart which will display the count for each Date by Dealer. Im struggling to find how to count the amount per day in order to put in the y axis.

```
Deal<-c("WEB","ASD","FGH","WEB","ASD","FGH","WEB","ASD","FGH")
    Date<-c("2020-01-03","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05","2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-07","2020-01-07")
    DD<-data.frame(Deal,Date)

# Multiple line plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DD, aes(x =Date , y = )) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Deal), size = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stat_count` in `geom_line` to count the number per day. This will skip over the days with zero counts so you might want to make these explicit by using `dplyr::count` and then filling the gaps, or by using `geom_bar` instead of `geom_line`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
DD <- data.frame(
  Deal = c("WEB","ASD","FGH","WEB","ASD","FGH","WEB","ASD","FGH"),
  Date = c("2020-01-03","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05","2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-07","2020-01-07")
) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))

# Multiple line plot
ggplot(DD, aes(x =Date)) + 
  geom_line(stat = "count", aes(color = Deal), size = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can group by Dealer and Date and get directly the count for each dealer by date. Here I used `count` from `dplyr` package (included in `tidyverse`). I also add `.drop = FALSE` in order to count for Dealer having a count of 0 for some dates:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
DD %>% group_by(Deal,Date, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  count()

# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   Deal, Date [15]
   Deal  Date           n
   <fct> <fct>      <int>
 1 ASD   2020-01-03     1
 2 ASD   2020-01-04     0
 3 ASD   2020-01-05     1
 4 ASD   2020-01-06     0
 5 ASD   2020-01-07     1
 6 FGH   2020-01-03     0
 7 FGH   2020-01-04     1
 8 FGH   2020-01-05     0
 9 FGH   2020-01-06     1
10 FGH   2020-01-07     1
11 WEB   2020-01-03     1
12 WEB   2020-01-04     0
13 WEB   2020-01-05     1
14 WEB   2020-01-06     0
15 WEB   2020-01-07     1
```

Then, you can pass this count into `ggplot2` by doing:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
DD %>% group_by(Deal,Date, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ymd(Date), y = n, color = Deal, group = Deal))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

NB: Here, I used the function `ymd` from `lubridate` package to convert your date into a date format on the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DD %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_date(Date)) %>% 
 group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(cnt = n_distinct(Deal)) %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x = Date , y = cnt)) + geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  theme_minimal()
```